# GWT - Activity (Presenter) without place

Tags: gwt2

I want to create web app with nested Activities. One activity will have nested other activity items. I want to use Slotted framework for GWT, but there is no good tutorial about it. I wonder if nested activities do need places?

I need template for website. Right panel(activity), left, center, top, breadcrumb. In center I want to have slots for presenters.

Answer (score 1):

GWT's [ActivityManager](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/activity/shared/ActivityManager.html) is tied to [PlaceChangeEvent](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/place/shared/PlaceChangeEvent.html). So, Yes you need to use "places" to make full use of Activity and ActivityManager concepts.

Note - [Activity](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/activity/shared/Activity.html) and AbstractActivity have no direct relation to "Places"

Answer (score 0):

Slotted has moved to GitHub and has move all the wikis here: https://github.com/slotted/slotted/wiki

There is a good tutorial for porting the standard GWT Activities and Places to Slotted here: https://github.com/slotted/slotted/wiki/Migrate-GWT-Activities-and-Places

As for an example of how to do different layouts, Slotted has an layout example here: https://github.com/slotted/slotted/tree/develop/examples/Layout